# How to create sub-nav when using a structured navigation heirarchy?

Tags: templating, sections, navigation

I have my navigation in a `Structure` like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMU8Y.png) and I want to build a sub-navigation on my Information page containing Specials, Reviews, and About, but I can't figure out how.

```
{% set active_item = craft.entries.section('navigation').nextSiblingOf(48).first() %}
```

doesn't give me what I need (and I really don't like handling with id's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an nice [recipe on the craftcookbook.net](http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/77) site from sprocketeer that explains exactly this.

```
{% set topEntry = craft.entries.depth(1).slug('information').first() %}
<ul>
    {% nav subEntry in topEntry.getDescendants() %}
        <li>{{ subEntry.title }}
            {% ifchildren %}<ul>{% children %}</ul>{% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>﻿
```